# Internet Explorer console log limitations on number of messages?

Tags: console, limit, internet-explorer-11

Firefox has console log limits that can be configured to my understanding, but I'm thinking the IE11 console also has a limit on the number of messages it logs before it fails and stops logging.

I was wondering why my later log messages were not showing up in the log and I would see console *warning* text of "An error has occurred in the JavaScript Console. Functionality might be affected." when there was no error logged.

So I stuck a simple loop to generate a bunch of log messages to the console.

```
var li=0;
for (li=0; li<500; ++li) console.log("li %d", li);

console.info("Finished with list of log entries.");
```

Along with the other informational console log messages I had (6 others) the list ended at 499, so I bumped up the cutoff to 5000:

```
var li=0;
for (li=0; li<5000; ++li) console.log("li %d", li);

console.info("Finished with list of log entries.");
```

Now the logging ends at "li 994" as the last line.
The "Finished..." line doesn't even display.
Looking up the console to see how many messages were displayed, I see there are 6 others, not of the "li xxx" type.

**So it *appears* that IE11 has a console limit of 1,000 entries and the stops logging and fails.**

**Can someone confirm and is there a way to set that limit higher?**

My javascript code does some array processing and there is a lot of array dumping of data that goes on.  I'm using console groups and they work, but when the entire logging shuts down after the 1000th message, that is a huge problem.